# Animate multiple attributes of single element with different animation attributes on each element attribute in svgjs

Tags: svg.js

I am attempting to create an effect with svgjs.  This effect requires, in my example, getting an item to zip back and forth, left to right to left.  I also want it to float up and down slightly, with the up-and-down animation duration distinct from the left-and-right, so it doesn't look obvious to the user that there is a loop (i.e. I *don't want there to be* a single loop for both axes).

One thing I've tried (`r` is a `rect`):

```
// horizontal
r.animate({
  duration: Math.random() * 4000 + 1000,
  swing: true,
  times: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
})
.attr({
  x: width - 10
})
// vertical
r.animate({
  duration: Math.random() * 4000 + 1000,
  swing: true,
  times: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
})
.attr({
  y: r.y() + (Math.random() * 250) - 125
})
```

With this code, the vertical animation never occurs because it is waiting for the horizontal loops to finish (which will effectively never happen).

I also tried this:

```
// horizontal
r.animate({
  duration: Math.random() * 4000 + 1000,
  swing: true,
  times: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
})
.attr({
  x: width - 10,
  y: r.y() + (Math.random() * 250) - 125
})
```

It works but looks boring/awkward, because the loop-ness is transparent to the viewer.

(Incidentally, if you can suggest a way to get these loops to last forever, other than setting `times: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` I'd be obliged, because that feels sloppy.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to schedule the animations to start at the same time. You can do that by passing the keyword `when: 'absolute'` to `animate()` which tells the runner to be scheduled at an absolute time on the timeline. Since both runners (aka calls to animate) are from the same element, they get scheduled on the same timeline. You can also use `now` as an alternative which basically stands for: start right now. But in that case it can happen that both of the animations are a few milliseconds apart.

Also you can use `times: true` or `times: Infinity` or just call `loop(true, true)`

```js
r.animate({when: 'absolute', delay: 0, ...}) // 0 is time on the timeline, can be dropped
r.animate({when: 'absolute', delay: 0, ...})
```

You can also pass this as multiple arguments and as I mentioned use `loop`:

```js
r.animate(Math.random() * 4000 + 1000, 0, 'absolute').loop(true, true) // loop(times, swing)
```

Comment: Unfortunately adding `when: 'absolute'` or `when: 'now'` had no effect, either with or without `delay: 0`.

Comment: Try it as extra parameters then

Comment: If you can update your answer to explain why the object property approach fails for me and/or remove that approach since it didn't seem to work, I'll happily accept the answer.  This has been quite useful.

Comment: You just found a bug. Looking through the code I found the issue where the passed parameters are used instead of the sanitized input which also keeps a possibly passed object into account. Let me fix that^^

Comment: @Steverino I published a new version which should fix this bug